# If-condition jumps to else-if statement, even though the if-condition is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested-loops

I am doing a challenge on FreeCodeCamp. 
My goal is to check whether `name` is an actual contact's `firstName` and the given property (`prop`) is a property of that contact.

The problem I am facing is that [in the first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdIH7.png) the if-statement comparison `name === contacts[i][prop]`
(*contacts* is the name of the array in which the objects I am looping over are located) 
returns true and the name gets logged, so everything is fine. 
Also notice here: the first **else-if** statement compares `name === contacts[i][prop]`, this changes in the second picture.

This is the code from the first picture:

```js
// Setup
var contacts = [
  {
    firstName: 'Akira',
    lastName: 'Laine',
    number: '0543236543',
    likes: ['Pizza', 'Coding', 'Brownie Points'],
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Harry',
    lastName: 'Potter',
    number: '0994372684',
    likes: ['Hogwarts', 'Magic', 'Hagrid'],
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Sherlock',
    lastName: 'Holmes',
    number: '0487345643',
    likes: ['Intriguing Cases', 'Violin'],
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Kristian',
    lastName: 'Vos',
    number: 'unknown',
    likes: ['JavaScript', 'Gaming', 'Foxes'],
  },
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (name === contacts[i][prop] && contacts[i]) {
      console.log(name);
      return;
    } else if (name === contacts[i][prop]) {
      console.log(name);
      console.log('No such contact');
      return;
    }
  }
}


lookUpProfile('Kristian', 'firstName');
```

This is the code-snippet from the second picture. The only changed thing here is the first else-if statement, where I changed `name === contacts[i][prop]` to `name !== contacts[i][prop]`

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (name === contacts[i][prop] && contacts[i]) {
      console.log(name);
      return;
    } else if (name !== contacts[i][prop]) {
      console.log(name);
      console.log('No such contact');
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

But if I change the first **else-if** statement to `name !== contacts[i][prop]`, as you can see [in the second picture,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlw3S.png) the **first else-if** statement gets executed, even tho I did not change the **if**-statement at all. Why is that.?

Comment: Do not post pictures, please paste the code here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm afraid I'm really struggling to understand your question.  You changed the condition in the first `else-if` line, so it seems reasonable that the block following it may now be executed when it might not have done before.  Could you please clarify the problem you have?  Try adding some examples of what your functions should log to the console for various input values and what they are currently logging.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Hey, as I am currently understanding if-statements, the if-condition should log the name to the console if the condition `name === contacts[i][prop] && contacts[i]` is true. The thing I don't understand is, why the first **else-if** statement gets executed, even though the if-statement is still true. Why does the first else-if-statement get executed, even tough the if-statement is still true?

Comment: Sorry for articulating myself so bad, my problem is: If I have the condition `name === contacts[i][prop]`in my else-if statement, the if-statement gets executed. But if I change the condition to `name !== contacts[i][prop]`, the else-if statement gets executed. Why does the else-if statement gets executed and not the if-statement, even tough the if-statement is still true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the question, as clarified in the comments, is as follows:

> Why does the else-if statement gets executed and not the if-statement, even t[h]ough the if-statement is still true?

The answer is because the `if`-statement is only true when `i = 3`, and the `else-if` statement is true when `i = 0`.

On the first iteration of the loop in your second `lookupProfile` function, `i` will be zero.  The condition `name === contacts[i][prop]` evaluates to `false` because the left-hand side is `Kristian` and the right-hand side is `Akira`. So the `if` block is skipped and the code jumps to the `else if`, where it checks the condition `name !== contacts[i][prop]`.  This condition evaluates to `true`, because the strings `Kristian` and `Akira` are not equal, so your code then logs the name `Kristian` and then the text `No such contact` and then returns from the function.

With the first version of your `lookupProfile` function, you have the conditions `name === contacts[i][prop] && contacts[i]` and `name === contacts[i][prop]`.  I'm not sure why you have the condition `contacts[i]` after the `&&`: this will check whether `contacts[i]` is truthy, but `contacts[i]` is an object so is never falsy.  Part of your task is to check that

> the given property (`prop`) is a property of that contact.

but `contacts[i]` won't be doing that because it doesn't involve `prop`.  As `contacts[i]` is always `true`, the condition `name === contacts[i][prop] && contacts[i]` is therefore equivalent to `name === contacts[i][prop]`, and this means that the `else if` in the first version of `lookupProfile` is never executed.

The first version of your function works well enough if the contact is in the list.  You seem to have got that bit working.  It seems however that you want to handle the case where the contact isn't in the list, but you haven't got the logic for that quite right.  What you can't say is that a contact is not in the list if they don't match *one* of the names: instead, they are not in the list if they don't match *all* of the names.  You can only be sure that a contact is not in the list by going through the whole list.

One way to do this is to introduce a variable, `found` say, which records whether the contact has been found.  Before the loop, we set it to `false`.  When the contact is found, set it to `true`.  If we get to the end of the loop and `found` is still `false`, we didn't find the contact.  However, since your function `return`s when it finds the contact, it would only reach any code below the loop if the contact was not found.  So you could put the line `console.log('No such contact');` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to gone through the below **official documentation**. These will make our code simple and our life easy.

1.[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

2.[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
    // Setup
    var contacts  = [
      {
        firstName: 'Akira',
        lastName: 'Laine',
        number: '0543236543',
        likes: ['Pizza', 'Coding', 'Brownie Points'],
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Harry',
        lastName: 'Potter',
        number: '0994372684',
        likes: ['Hogwarts', 'Magic', 'Hagrid'],
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Sherlock',
        lastName: 'Holmes',
        number: '0487345643',
        likes: ['Intriguing Cases', 'Violin'],
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Kristian',
        lastName: 'Vos',
        number: 'unknown',
        likes: ['JavaScript', 'Gaming', 'Foxes'],
      },
    ];

    function lookUpProfile(name , prop ) {
      let Key =contacts[0].hasOwnProperty(prop);
      if(!Key){
        console.log('Property is not found');
        return;
      }
      
      let data = contacts.find(item => name === item[prop]);
      if(data){
         console.log('Matched')
      }else{
  console.log('Not Matched')
      }
    }

    lookUpProfile('Kristian', 'firstName');
    lookUpProfile('Kristian', 'lastName');
    lookUpProfile('Laine', 'lastName');
    lookUpProfile('Laine', 'last');
```